# What is the best percentage to divide data sets for PNN and SVM neural network training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have about 1100 sample sets, each of 18 values. Please suggest an optimal division percentage for Training/Validation/Evaluation. I'm using PNN and SVM neural nets for classification problem with 3 possible outcomes.

Please also explain your reasoning.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there would be any optimal answer, but would really come down to how well the Neural Network is performing on the training data.

I've usually split the data 60/20/20, but this could change depending on the quality and complexity of the data.

You could run a few tests with different combinations and see how that affects your validation / evaluation performance.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you hava a good approach to classify this dataSet, is to apply the [Cross-Validation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). Give you are using three sets such as `training set`, `validation set` and `test set`, supose you divide the entire set in five parts of 20% each. With this you could rearrange these parts in order to make sure you have tested your model in all entire set.

i.

```
[1, 2, 3] - training
[4] - validation
[5] - test
```

ii.

```
[2, 3, 4] - training
[5] - validation
[1] - test
```

iii.

```
[3, 4, 5] - training
[1] - validation
[2] - test
```

iv.

```
[4, 5, 1] - training
[2] - validation
[3] - test
```

v.

```
[5, 1, 2] - training
[3] - validation
[4] - test
```

I think there is no perfect approach, you could explore the dataSet on your apporach and see the results. You do not need to preserve the order too.